# Prove that if $A$ is symmetric and nonsingular, then $A^{-1}$ is symmetric

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, symmetric-matrices

Here is my attempt:

If $A$ is nonsingular and $A=A^T$, then $A^{-1}A=A^{-1} A^T=I_n.$ Since $A^T$ is nonsingular, we multiply $(A^T)^{-1}$ on both sides and we get $(A^T)^{-1}I_n=A^{-1}I_n \implies (A^T)^{-1}=(A^{-1})^T=A^{-1}$. Thus $A^{-1}$ is symmetric.

In the instructor's manual, the proof goes like this:

We must show that $(A^{−1})^T = A^{−1}.$ First, $AA^{−1} = I_n$ implies that $(AA^{−1})^T = I_n^{T} = I_n$.

Now $(AA^{−1})^T = (A^{−1})^TA^T = (A^{−1})^{T}A$, which means that $(A^{−1})^T = A^{−1}$.

Is the author's approach more efficient, moreover, is my approach valid?

Comment: The difference is this: you don't need to repeat the uniqueness proof of one-sided inverse of an invertible matrix.

Comment: I don't follow your logic here. You multiply "both sides" by $(A^T)^{-1}$ (which is the same as $A^{-1}$, since $A$ and $A^T$ are the same, by assumption), but both sides of what? From your next step, it seems to be both sides of the equation $I_n = I_n$, which does not strike me as helpful. I have no idea how the next implication follows either.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I intended to multiply $(A^T)^{-1}$ to both sides of the equation $A^{−1}A^{T}=I_n$ which would give us $(A^T)^{-1}I_n=A^{−1}A^{T}(A^T)^{-1}$. The $A^{T}(A^T)^{-1}$ simplifies to $I_n$ and we are left with $(A^T)^{−1}I_n=A^{−1}I_n$. And since the product of the identity matrix and any n x m matrix is itself, we end up with $(A^T)^{−1}=(A^{-1})^T=A^{−1}$

Comment: @dutch Ah, that makes a bit more sense (be aware that when multiplying both sides of an equation by a matrix, you need to be clear whether you are multiplying from the left or the right), though the final step still somewhat mysterious. Simplifying the $I_n$s out, you get $(A^T)^{-1} = A^{-1}$ (which, as I mentioned in the previous comment, follows immediately from $A = A^T$). How do you get from this to a conclusion about $(A^{-1})^T$?

Comment: In hindsight, I realize that my approach is redundant now that you are asking about how I arrived at such a conclusion. My intention was to somehow use the theorem that $(A^T)^{-1}=(A^{-1})^T$ to arrive at $A^{-1}=(A^{-1})^T$. Through further speculation, it is starting to make more sense now why the author chose his approach.